# How to select firrst column date and second column time as Datetime

Tags: sql, date, time

I want to select the date part of first field and time part minus 3 hours of second field as datetime. I have tried the following way, it is taking only hours of time field as I am taking only hours. How can achieve it by converting complete date and time minus 3 hours. Please help me if any simple ways are there

```
declare @ReminderDate DATETIME='2013-12-22 01:01:01.000' 
declare @ReminderTime DATETIME='2014-09-10 14:09:00.000'

select cast(cast(cast( @ContactMadeReminderDate as DATE) as nvarchar(15))+' ' + cast(LEFT(CONVERT(TIME(0), @ContactMadeReminderTime), 2)-3  as nvarchar(15) ) +':00' as datetime)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(@ReminderDate AS Date) AS DateTime) + CAST(DATEADD(HOUR,-3,@ReminderTime) AS TIME)
```